# Could not read Password for "https://username@bitbucket.org":No such device or address

Tags: 14.04, git, rabbitvcs

I am developing a laravel web application with three members team. We using Bitbucket version control, I cloned my repository from Terminal, now I switch the Git usage UI software RabibtCVS.

I installed the software and need to update my files.
When i select **update** from right click menu on folder its showing below error message.

[image]

Is there any configuration needed for using RabbitCVS ?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use SmartGit 3.0.10 (as well as SmartGitHg, the predecessor of SmartGit).

**To add the PPA run:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

To install smartgit (after adding the PPA) run:

```
sudo apt-get install smartgit
```

To install smartgithg (after adding the PPA) run:

```
sudo apt-get install smartgithg
```

This should add a menu option for you

For more information, see Eugene San PPA.